# Another way of saying "running from place to place"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

I'm looking for another way of saying that I have been busy, moved around a lot  this year as have been preoccupied.

> This year has been  filled with emotions and full of new exciting
>   challenges,
>
> `  (a lot of running from place to place.)
>
> The most hectic year of my life.

Answer (score 1):

**[Nomadic](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/nomadic)**

> A nomad is someone who lives by traveling from place to place. Nomadic
>   thus means anything that involves moving around a lot. Nomadic
>   hunter-gatherer tribes follow the animals they hunt, carrying tents
>   with them.
>
> You don't have to be a nomad to live a nomadic lifestyle. People who
>   work for the state department travel from foreign country to foreign
>   country in four-year postings––they might call this nomadic. If you
>   change schools a lot because of your parents' moves, you could say
>   you've had a nomadic education.

[Vocabulary.com]

Answer (score 0):

**helter-skelter**  [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/helter-skelter)

> with undue hurry and confusion; pell-mell, hurried; **lacking a visible
>   order or organization**;  “a helter-skelter kind of existence with never
>   a pause”

As in your case and example:

> ```
> This year has been filled with emotions, new exciting challenges, and
>
> a lot of running from place to place. Truly a most **helter-skelter** year.
> ```

Synonyms of **helter-skelter** (same link) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Consider **bustle**:

> *verb*
>
> 1. Move in an energetic and busy manner.
>      *‘people clutching clipboards bustled about’*
>
> > 1.2  (of a place) be full of activity.
> >     *‘the streets bustled with people’*
>
> *noun*
>
> Excited activity and movement.
>       *‘all the noise and the traffic and the bustle’*
>
> [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bustle)

---

Also **hustle and bustle**:

> Busy and frenetic activity or excitement.
>   *I love living among the hustle and bustle of the city. I avoid the hustle and bustle of malls and shopping centers whenever I can.*
>
> [Farlex Dictionary of Idioms.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hustle+and+bustle)

Answer (score -1):

If you need a one-root word, I would recommend you 'To commute'.

According to Oxford Living Dictionary:

***commute***

VERB

// Travel some distance between one's home and place of work on a regular basis.

‘he commuted from Corby to Kentish Town’

‘But many Japanese suffer from the distances they commute to work.’

‘The new entrance will be welcome news for the large population of commuters now living at that end of the town, most of who are commuting on a daily basis to Dublin.’

‘In order to recreate some of the atmosphere of those ‘happy days’, I am heading off home to Suffolk this evening in order to spend the next four days commuting to Cambridge and back from Ipswich.’

‘Additionally, up to 130,000 passengers enter and leave the city by train and by air, who also commute to and from the railway station or the airport.’

‘Twenty-five years ago very few people were commuting to Galway from South Mayo on a daily basis to work.’

‘An estimated 37,000 people regularly commute to the Swindon area, of which 23,000 make the journey on a daily basis.’

‘After spending five months commuting weekly to London, she accepted a temporary post at in Birmingham and there covered regional news programmes and documentaries.’

‘A significant number of people commute daily to London, offset by commuters into Brighton and Hove from the surrounding county.’

‘We are also looking at people travelling, commuting to Dublin to ascertain the traffic flows, he said.’

‘Yes, I'm fully aware that traffic may well slow you down when commuting from place to place, especially in urban settings but leave a little earlier to take that into account.’

‘Do you commute to work or spend a lot of time travelling to meetings and conferences?’

‘If people are commuting to urban areas, we need to make sure they are participating in the communities they are living in.’

‘If people in the Bolton area stop using their cars for commuting, they can forget about switching to the railways because, even before the removal of the above mentioned trains, existing services are filled to capacity.’

‘It is just not realistic to expect urban workers to commute long distances on a daily basis to reach their place of work.’

‘He has been commuting to London on a weekly basis for four years.’

‘Anyone using ferries to commute or travel on business is going to want to cut down the time involved and will choose the new fast ferries in preference to the older slower vessels.’

‘Claire, a student radiographer who commutes regularly between Skipton and Bradford, found the trains to be very unreliable.’

‘I personally think that is an excellent idea, it cuts down players travelling and also makes commuting for supporters easier.’

‘Many people spend much of their working week travelling in cars, trains, etc. commuting to and from their places of employment.’

‘Hundreds commute on a daily basis from my constituency to the capital.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with the question.