# Is there a word or expression that describes a situation where a person repetitively "comes and goes"?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

In Levantine Arabic, the expression "siri miri" (سِرِّي مِرِّي) is used for someone who continually and incessantly comes and goes, or passes by, such as like near your house or just about anywhere, to the point of absurdity. It can also be used for someone who frequently leaves and returns, going back and forth.

Examples:

*This guy is passing by my house all the time, back and forth, nonstop. What is with this [insert idiom/term] behaviour?*

*This person is always going and returning. He is [insert term/expression] all the time. I wonder why.*

EDIT:

There is **NO DUPLICATION**. The thread I made on the Kuwaiti Arabic idiom ("*khiri miri*") pertains to **lack of rules, chaos and/or disorder**. "Willy-nilly" seemed to be an appropriate English equivalent for it.

"***Siri miri***" is a Syrian expression that pertains to **someone walking back & forth, or going and returning** in a frequent manner. It does NOT pertain to haphazardness and disorder. Please don't be fooled by how the terms soundalike in Arabic, **when they don't quite mean the same thing.**

Comment: This seems really similar to https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/612333/what-is-a-term-or-idiom-for-someone-who-enters-and-exits-without-a-request-or/ The most upvoted and accepted answer given was [willy nilly](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/612378/326523).

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're looking for in terms of this answer? Are you looking for something that rhymes, are you looking for something formal? Are you looking for a single word or an idiom?

Comment: It wouldn't exactly fit in your sentences, but _to and fro_ is an adverbial phrase referring to repeated 'coming and going' movement. "He's going to and fro past my house all the time."

Comment: One expression may fit to your last example : "He is constantly [on the move](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+move)".

Comment: Is this behavior (to and fro) something typical  of some people where you live? If so why do these people move to and from continually?

Comment: Does the guy come onto your property? - perhaps even enter your house unauthorised?  *Why* does he keep passing by, and how do you come to be aware of this? Do you spend all day looking out your front window to see if any of the passers-by are *repeats?* I think the context is so bizarre we need much more info on what's actually going on before we can suggest idiomatic ways to refer to it in English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  There wasn't a way to give you two points for that comment, so I've given you one and deducted one from the question, pending further context to justify the  description of the situation as an "absurdity".

Comment: Could just be a commuter.

Comment: It should be noted that there are a dozen different meanings of "come and go".

Comment: Could be a would-be ***burglar***, "casing the joint".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a term (or idiom) for someone who enters and exits without a request or order?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/612333/what-is-a-term-or-idiom-for-someone-who-enters-and-exits-without-a-request-or)

Comment: @SlowlySwift I'm happy with an informal or formal term, an idiom. Whatever fits.

Comment: @Casey I just made an additional edit regarding this, to clear it out. I made the thread that you linked. The answers were very helpful and everything's resolved. In this case, "siri miri" pertains to coming and going, leaving and returning, incessantly and repetitively. It doesn't mean chaos and disorder, like the term in that question you linked. So the two expressions are different, even if somewhat similar. Thanks.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The term is just simply used for someone who repetitively and annoying passes by, gets inside & out, goes back and forth.

Comment: Well, I would give the exact same answer again.

Comment: @Casey You mean waltzing? It is acceptable. Fits better here though.

Comment: You gave examples sentences with a blank and in the examples you've already mentioned "back and forth" and "going and returning". It didn't look like you are looking for an alternative to "going back and forth", and you've mentioned they're doing it to the point of absurdity. _Erratic_ describes this behaviour and it fits your examples as the blanks require an adjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This guy is passing by my house all the time,

This guy is **toing and froing** by my house all the time,

to to and fro -

OED

> As adverb:
>
> **1.a.Successively to and from some place, etc.; hence more vaguely: In opposite or different directions alternately; with alternating
> movement; from side to side; backwards and forwards; hither and
> thither; up and down.**
>
> 1855 The pendulum which has been..swung to and fro, is at last about
> to settle. A. P. Stanley, Hist. Memorials Canterbury (1857) ii.
>
> As verb **to to and fro**
>
> **VERB** intransitive. **To pass to and fro, to go hither and thither.**
>
> 1904 Why all this secrecy about these to-ings and fro-ings?
> Westminster Gazette 28 November 2/2

From "The Room in the Dragon Volant (conclusion). Carmilla" By Joseph Sheridan Le Fanu

> I soon saw that it was a sooty-black animal that resembled a monstrous cat. It appeared to me about four or five feet long, for it measured fully the length of the hearth-rug as it passed over it; and it continued toing and froing with the lithe sinister restlessness of a beast in a cage.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! Perfect English equivalent!

Answer (score 1):

*To and fro* is a good suggestion,as is *back and forth*.

Here is *Wiktionary*:
**back and forth**

> Going from one place or position to another and back again.

*The back and forth movement of the tide causes erosion of the coastline.*

Answer (score 1):

***Comings and goings***

Has the sense of "constant in and out" (as per Google's definition):

*Busy, active movements of many people, especially in and out of a place.*

And as well as "arriving and leaving" (as per Collins' definition):

*Comings and goings refers to the way people keep arriving at and leaving a particular place.*

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/comings-and-goings

Answer (score 0):

> This person is always **popping in and out**. I wonder why.

> **To pop in and out**: to come and go frequently or casually; to visit for a short time, esp. without prior arrangement.
>
> **1846** He could have profited very little by his series of flying visits to all the sections which he kept popping in and out of.
> *Times* 19 September 4/2
>
> **1995** An informal arrangement opens the grandparents to conflicts with their own children, who can pop in and out of their lives.
> *Minnesota Monthly* January 130/2
> [OED]

> (Often **pop in/out**) go or come for a short time, often without notice.
> [Concise Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Concise_Oxford_English_Dictionary/4XycAQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=pop%20in%20and%20out%20without%20notice&pg=PA1116&printsec=frontcover)

---

> Of course with Circe living here, maybe they're all used to people
> **popping in and out of the neighborhood**.
> [Mel Odom; *I'll Zap Manhattan*](https://course%20with%20Circe%20living%20here%20,%20maybe%20they%27re%20all%20used%20to%20people%20popping%20in%20and%20out%20of%20the%20neighborhood%20.) (1999)

> Secretaries, who had never seen an American before, found excuses to
> **pop in and out of the office**, to ask about more refreshments, to bring a new plate of cookies, or just to stare at us through the open
> office door.
> [Martin Scheffer; *In Post-Communist Worlds: Living and
> Teaching in Estonia*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/In_Post_Communist_Worlds/_UhAVH7ljhAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22pop%20in%20and%20out%20of%20the%20office%22&pg=PA113&printsec=frontcover) (2009)

> The praire-dogs have all got their holes, and though you may see 'em
> going about **popping in and out of each other's houses**, I fancy as
> they always keep to their own. But there's one hole which they all
> use, and that goes down to the water.
> [G. A. Henty; *Times of War & Peril*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/TIMES_OF_WAR_PERIL_The_Historical_Novels/0rToDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22popping%20in%20and%20out%22&pg=PT4007&printsec=frontcover) (2019)